# Connection string for using SQL Server Compact with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I'm done trying to Google for this. I have installed SQL Server CE 4.0, and have EF 4.1, but I can't get a proper connection string. Nothing on `connectionstrings.com` applies to me.

I just want to create a `SqlCeEngine` object, but no matter what I try I get some exception. Most recently it's been

> Unknown connection option in connection string

with either "metadata", "app", "provider", or "provider connection string" after it. I know EF requires metadata in the connection string. And I can't imagine how anything could do without "provider connection string".

So far I have this:

```
<add name="DBContext" 
     connectionString="provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyDbFile.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

At one point I had it with metadata:

```
<add name="DBContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.DBContext.csdl|res://*/Data.DBContext.ssdl|res://*/Data.DBContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MyDbFile.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Does it need metadata or not? What goes in the "app" part of the connection string? What should the provider be, `System.Data.SqlClient` or some SQL Server CE version? (which I still can't find when I try to add references. My add references window still only contains `System.Data.SqlServerCe` version 3.5.1.0.) Or nothing?

And what should go in the `providerName` attribute? Is `System.Data.EntityClient` correct? It's like there are 10 different variables here and every combination gives me a new equally mysterious error, none of which turns up anything useful on Google. I'm at my wits' end. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 13):

You could try this in your App.config file (EF5 Code first migrations and SQL Server CE 4.0):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data\ProjectDb.sdf"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And in you `ProjectDb` class:

```
class ProjectDb : DbContext
{
    public ProjectDb()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

It will work like a charm.

You can find more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx

Comment: What about relative paths? Say you are testing a db from a test project? Any chance we could modify the connection string to use a relative path instead to say where the database is?

Comment: Dude, "|DataDirectory|\Data\ProjectDb.sdf" is a relative path

Answer (score 6):

I’d stuck with the same problem on Entity Framework 5.0 Code First approach with SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0

To solve it I pass instance of `SqlCeConnection` to `DbContext`'s constructor:

```
public class Storage : DbContext
{
    public Storage()
        : base(new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"),
             contextOwnsConnection: true)
    { }

    //...
}
```

If you don’t want to inline connection string you could get it from *App.config* through `ConfigurationManager`
And of course you should add reference to the right version of System.Data.SqlServerCe (look inside Extentions tab in the Add Reference dialog)

Answer (score 0):

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835495.aspx) outlines the steps for using EF with SQL Server Compact. This line jumped out at me, and may solve your problems:

> make sure that **provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5** in the connection
>   string.

(I would assume that you would want 4.0 instead of 3.5)

Give that a try and see how things go.

Comment: Still gives me an unknown connection option error, for that very provider property.

Comment: This post (http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html) indicates that you need to change the edmx file as well as the config file, but it's also nearly a year old. I'd be surprised if the VS support for that hasn't been taken care of, but there's no telling...

Answer (score 0):

The Lu55's solution didn't work for me, but I found fow to fix it. To still use the automatic code generation (which can overwrite changes in a generated file), I added one more file with the following code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace MyProject.Data
{
    internal partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities(string connectionString)
            : base(
                new ObjectContext(
                        @"metadata=res://*/Data.Model.csdl|
                                   res://*/Data.Model.ssdl|
                                   res://*/Data.Model.msl;
                          provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;"),
                true)
        {
            Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed a bit.

For SQL Server CE connection string can be quite easy (possibly replace `DbContext` with `YourNameSpace.DbContextName`):

```
<add name="DbContext" 
     connectionString="MyDbFile.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

I also had a lot of trouble with connections, so I did the following:

- [installed Entity Framework for SQL Server CE](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact)
- Checked that web.config contains provider with invariant `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0`
- Verified that there are NO string fields (which will be represented as columns in db) with length max or mode than 4000 symbols (to add restriction use annotation `[MaxLength(4000)]`, by default == MAX)

Metadata are necessary when you use database-first model instead of code-first, so there is `.edmx` file which represents generated model of the database.