# mvc4 : An error occurred while getting provider information from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting an error while trying to write data to database.
I'm using sqlservercompact 4.0 and have installed entityframework.sqlservercompact from nuget package. 
Here is my installed references
[image]
Edit: as per answer I have changed my provider name but I get new error that says`Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.`

```
 public class PortalContext : DbContext
        {
            public PortalContext() : base("AdminPortal")
            {

            }

            public DbSet<RegisterModel> Users { get; set; } 
        }
```

name of my database is `AdminPortal` and table name is `Users` and in web.config i have

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdminPortal" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Biplov\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BootstrappingMvc\BootstrappingMvc\App_Data\AdminPortal.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

in controller I have

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                var regUser = _db.Users.Create();//error at this line

                regUser.UserName = user.UserName;
                regUser.Password = user.Password;

                _db.Users.Add(regUser);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Is that the correct format for a SQL Server Compact database?  You don't include any security information, for example.  Also, I'm not sure that would be the right provider name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Compact doesn't use the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider for embedded databases, it used `System.Data.SqlServerCe` doesn't it?

Comment: I changed the providername as you mentioned but now the error says`Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.` So does that mean I haven't installed the database? Cause I have

Comment: There may be more things wrong here.  Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947325/connection-string-for-using-sql-server-compact-with-entity-framework here for some guidance.